# C: Comparing hash value seems to disappear

Tags: c

For the love of holy code, I am trying to compare hashes to find the correct password. I am given a hash as a command line argument, and I then hash words from "a" to "ZZZZ" until one of the hash pairs match.

```
void decipher(string hash)
{
    //Set the password, and the salt.
    char pass[4] = "a";
    char salt[] ="50";

    //Compare the crypted pass againts the hash until found. 
    while (strcmp(hash,crypt(pass, salt)) != 0)
    {
        //Use int i to hold position, and return next char
          int i = 0;
          pass[i] = get_next(pass[i]);
          tick_over (pass, i);

          //Hardcode in a fail safe max length: exit.
          if (strlen(pass) > 4)
            {
               break;
            }
    }
    printf("%s\n", pass);
}
```

The problem is that it will not 'catch' the correct password / comparison, when that password is 4 letters long. It works for 1,2 and 3 letter long words.

```
//Tick over casino style
string tick_over (string pass, int i)
{
    //Once a char reaches 'Z', move the next char in line up one value.
    char a[] = "a";
    if (pass[i] == 'Z')
    {
      if (strlen(pass) < i+2)
      {
        strncat (pass, &a[0], 1);
        return pass;
      }
      pass[i+1] = get_next(pass[i+1]);
      //Recursively run again, moving along the string as necessary
      tick_over (pass, i+1);
    }
    return pass;
}

//Give the next character in the sequence of available characters 
char get_next (char y)
{
    if (y == 'z')
    {
        return 'A';
    }
    else if (y == 'Z')
    {
        return 'a';
    }
    else 
    {
        return y + 1;
    }
}
```

It does iterate through the correct word, as I have found in debugging. I have tried moving the

```
strcmp(hash, crypt(pass, salt)) == 0
```

into a nested if statement among other things, but it doesn't seem to be the problem. Is c somehow 'forgetting' the command line value? When debugging the hash value seemed to have disappeared :/ Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char pass[4] = "a";` you're defining a char array which can contain at most 3 chars + null terminator.

that's not coherent with your "safety" test: `if (strlen(pass) > 4)`

When `strlen` is 4 the array is already overwriting something in memory because of the null termination char: *undefined behaviour*.

Quickfix: `char pass[5] ...`

Comment: Thank you this worked. However, earlier before creating the tick_over method and the 'safety' test, pass[4] did work - in that the password hash would match and break from the loop.  I'm curious - would you know why that might have happened, is it the safety test that caused the overwrite?

Comment: but you did have undefined behaviour because you were writing out of bounds. So that's like Russian roulette. At some point you lose. The safety test only reads so no. It's any write operation outside the bounds. RAM is cheap. Enlarge the buffer and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation of the function `strncat`:

> Append characters from string
>   Appends the first num characters of source to destination, **plus a terminating null-character**.

with a size of 4 you are not considering the terminating null character of your four chars array.